# Flink program works from IDE but not from terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, apache-flink

I have 5 different Jobs, some of them have an InputFormat and others use env.fromElements(...)

When I execute the Jobs using IntelliJ, all of them works correctly. But when I execute them from terminal, only jobs which contains env.fromElements() works.

Here is the error message:

```
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:6123
Using address localhost:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://localhost:8081
Starting execution of program
Submitting job with JobID: ab41f30df416c654b406c9b13e70f62e. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123/user/jobmanager#1320020477]


The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Cannot initialize task 'CHAIN DataSource (at main(JobSource.java:49) (es.mypackage.flink.Sources.MyInputFormat)) -> Map (Map at main(JobSource.java:53))': Configuring the InputFormat (es.mypackage.flink.Sources.MyInputFormat@1f81aa00) failed: null
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:427)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:101)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:400)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:387)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:926)
at es.mypackage.flink.Job.JobSource.main(JobSource.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:528)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:419)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:339)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:831)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:256)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1073)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1120)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend$2.call(CliFrontend.java:1117)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext$1.run(HadoopSecurityContext.java:43)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:40)
at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1116)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'CHAIN DataSource (at main(JobSource.java:49) (es.mypackage.flink.Sources.MyInputFormat)) -> Map (Map at main(JobSource.java:53))': Configuring the InputFormat (es.mypackage.flink.Sources.MyInputFormat@1f81aa00) failed: null
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:136)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob(JobManager.scala:1274)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1.applyOrElse(JobManager.scala:477)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LeaderSessionMessageFilter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LeaderSessionMessageFilter.scala:36)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:33)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.apply(LogMessages.scala:28)
at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$$anon$1.applyOrElse(LogMessages.scala:28)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.aroundReceive(JobManager.scala:118)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Configuring the InputFormat (es.mypackage.flink.Sources.MyInputFormat@1f81aa00) failed: null
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.InputFormatVertex.initializeOnMaster(InputFormatVertex.java:89)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ExecutionGraphBuilder.java:133)
... 20 more
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:

```
public void configure(Configuration parameters) {

    /*This line causes the problem*/
    this.client  = new KuduClient.KuduClientBuilder(KUDU_MASTER).build();

    table = createTable(TABLE_NAME);
    if (table != null) {
        scanner = client.newScannerBuilder(table)
                .setProjectedColumnNames(projectColumns)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the fat jar for running from within the command line?

Comment: I use the jar generated on /target @DawidWysakowicz

Comment: It seems sth wrong is happening in the configure method of your `MyInputFormat`. Could you post your code in there?

Comment: I edit the question adding the method, but i dont know how it can works from IDE perfectly (the line which causes the problem is a third party method so i cant modify) @DawidWysakowicz

Comment: Ok, so one more question then, how do you exactly run the jar? The program run from within Intellij runs on a MiniCluster on the localhost. Is it also the case when you run from cli or do you submit it to some remote cluster? Also the exception that is thrown from the KuduClientBuilder would be more helpful than the one provided. Also the configure method is not the best place to open any connections. The right place to do so is the open method of InputFormat.

Comment: First i start flink using bin/start-local.sh 

Which prints Starting jobmanager daemon on host vadi-VirtualBox.


Then i run the flink cluster /bin/start-cluster.sh

Starting cluster.
Starting jobmanager daemon on host vadi-VirtualBox.
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

If i try to start again the cluster it says
Starting cluster.
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of jobmanager are already running on vadi-VirtualBox.

So i supose that the cluster started correctly @DawidWysakowicz

Comment: P.D @DawidWysakowicz when i generate the jar i run some tests that do exactly the same than my main class, and those test works perfectly, my brain is breaking right now :s

Comment: Ok, bare in mind though that running the code from IDE differs significantly from operational view than deploying into cluster. First of all you should not use the start-local.sh and start-cluster.sh at the same time. They both create a flink cluster(one in local mode with embedded taskmanager the second one a standalone cluster. Have a look at the https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/cluster_setup.html). You need to make sure that all taskmanagers have access to your KUDU_MASTER. I also strongly advise to move the KuduClient instantiation to open method.